# Deleting a program after a certain amount of days using a batch file

Tags: php, batch-file

I wrote a PHP script for DevelStudio that creates a batch file, inserts commands and runs it, but it gives me an unexpected T_STRING error on 2nd line, but I cant understand whats exacly wrong

```
$edit1 = c('Form2->edit1')->text;
$batcode = "forfiles -p "c:\kursach" -s -m *.* /D -$edit1 /C "cmd /c del @path"" 
//the code that will be inserted in run.bat
$file = 'run.bat'; //name of the batch file
file_put_contents($file, $batcode.'"'. EXE_NAME . '"'); //insert $batcode in $file (run.bat)
run($file);  //starts a batch file
```

Comment: you need to escape the double quotes on the second line, the exact issue is that you are hopping in and out of the string, if you add a `\\` to all double quotes "inside" the string you'll be fine

Comment: It shows the same error

Comment: You have embedded double quotes. Your string is being interpreted as several strings (**"forfiles -p"** c:\kursach **"-s -m *.* /D - $edit1 /C "** cmd /c del @path **""**)  - I've bolded every other separate string for clarity. And we would think you **didn't tried that yet** because you've not told us that you have. Don't expect us to have information that you have not provided to us. We're not mind readers. If you want us to know what you've already tried, **put it in your question**. And be a little more polite. You're the one asking us for **free help** to solve **your problem**.

Comment: I think you haven't tried that because the code you've offered up for review HASN'T TRIED THAT, by the way even stackoverflow's code highlighter has highlighted the errors

Comment: Marko Polo We are not here to guess what you did and what not. Be polite and explain what you tried and what not.

Comment: `$batcode = "forfiles -p "c:\kursach" -s -m *.* /D -$edit1 /C "cmd /c del @path""` < is missing a closing statement character, being a semi-colon.

Answer (score 2):

On the second line you need to escape the inner `'"'` characters as `'\"'` or change the outer ones to `'`.

E.g:

```
$batcode = "forfiles -p \"c:\kursach\" -s -m *.* /D -$edit1 /C \"cmd /c del @path\""
```

Or

```
$batcode = 'forfiles -p "c:\kursach" -s -m *.* /D -$edit1 /C "cmd /c del @path"'
```